# Why tbl_summary() function is not found even though I have installed gtsummary packages

Tags: r, gtsummary

I would like to create a table of summary statistics for Patient baseline demographics, and clinical characteristics overall with R studio

In R studio, I am working in Rmarkdown
I have installed packages:

## Loading useful packages

```
pacman::p_load(
    dplyr,
    readxl,
    ggplot2,
    tidyr,
    gtsummary
    )
```

Then I have selected the variables I would like to have some statistics about and apply the tbl_summary function:

```
tsum <- df %>%
    select(gender,
           age,
           ethnicity,
           level_educ,
           marital_status,
           sociopro_class,
           alcohol,
           smoker,
           bmi_ctgcbm,
           ncds,
           stge_hiv
           ) %>% 
    tbl_summary()
```

I was not expecting this error message: Error in tbl_summary(.) : could not find function "tbl_summary"

Comment: Please prepare your question after the guidelines. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask), as well as [how to write the "perfect" question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), especially its [checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/)